# how to solve Error 32 pipe when expand .tar in mac lion

Tags: macos, maven, terminal, root

I hadn't any problem before installing apache maven ,since I had a mistake in installing apache maven (I copy all file of this folder in my local folder)and I think something wrong happen in my local folder 
inside of apache maven is :

```
bin folder
boot folder
conf folder
lib folder
LICENSE.txt
NOTICE.txt
README.txt
```

after that I have error 32 pipe when I want to extract .tar file and also I can't update my software via software update in mac.

Is there anyone can help me?

Here is the exact error:

Unable to expand "filename.tar"  into Downloads. "error 32 - Broken pipe"

Comment: It might help if you include the exact error message in quotes.

Comment: Here is the exact error:

Unable to expand "filename.tar" into Downloads. "error 32 - Broken pipe"

Comment: Can you post your PATH environment variable as well as the command you're executing when you get the error message you supplied?

Comment: @Chris my path is /usr/local/bin, when I double clicking on .tr file I will get this error :  Unable to expand "filename.tar" into Downloads. "error 32 - Broken pipe" --> it can be in desktop ,in dounloads ,documnet ..... folder..

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is unrelated to Maven. In fact try deleting it and see.

Comment: yes I know, but since I had a mistake in installing apache maven (I copy all file of this folder in my local folder) and unfortunatelyI don't know why I didn't read the message when I copy and I just said yes and something happen in my local folder, maybe replace, after that i had error ..